# Changing to a smaller gear ratio

Tags: gears, sram, gravel

I have a Kona Rove ST, with a 40 teeth gear wheel and a 11-42 cassette. It's all SRAM. [Here](https://2019.konaworld.com/rove_st.cfm) is the technical description.

It's ok for now, but I'm often using the smallest ratio (40x42) so I don't have any margin. Hence, I'd like to have a smaller gear ratio. To make it more complicated, I like my biggest ratio just fine, but I guess I'll have to compromise and lessen it.

But lowering my smaller ratio seems quite complicated and/or so expensive. So I thought I could just change the gear wheel for a smaller one. It seems straightforward to replace it with a 38 teeth one, but I'm not so sure for a 36 teeth one.

So my questions are: is it worth it to replace my gear wheel with a 38 or 36 one, and if so is it easy to do so? (especially for the 36 teeth)
Or is there any other solution that would work?

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a 1x setup you don't have to worry about the front derailleur, so it's definitely possible to swap in a smaller chainring.  That *will* affect your highest gear too though, so you should bear that in mind.

I don't see any reason for there to be a problem switching to a 36t chainring, noting that 36x42 is only 10% less than 40x42.  Maybe that's enough of an improvement; it's up to you to judge how much easier you need it.  It will reduce your max speed - for a given cadence - by about 10% as well in your top gear.

The [SRAM X-Sync chainring](https://r2-bike.com/SRAM-Force-1-Rival-1-Chainring-1-speed-BCD-110-X-SYNC-black) has a 5-bolt, 110mm bolt-centre diameter (BCD) mounting, (sample link only) so you need to find a compatible chainring.  Again, not to make a recommendation, but a quick search found a 36t [Wolf Tooth 1x chainring](https://www.jensonusa.com/Wolf-Tooth-110-BCD-Cyclocross-Road-Chainrings) with a matching bolt configuration.

It *is* possible to find a cassette with a bigger range (though not a SRAM 11-speed) but that would require you to replace your rear derailleur as well, since the [SRAM Rival 1 derailleur](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-riv-1-a2) your bike comes with has a max of 42.  This is almost definitely not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

SRAM's [page for the S350 crank](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/fc-s350-1-a1) lists 44, 42, 40 and 38 chainring size variants, so you can definitely swap in a 38 tooth ring with no compatibility issues.

The chainring bolt pattern is equally spaced 5 bolts. SRAM does not specify the bolt center diameter (BCD) but it's presumably a standard one, which means there should be third-party narrow-wide 1x rings available. With a bit of searching you may find a 36 tooth one that will fit.